# libspotify/ pyspotify segmentation fault randomly when creating session

Tags: python, python-2.7, libspotify

So everything works correctly, and I haven't changed any of my code. At all. However, sometimes randomly I'll run the SAME EXACT PROGRAM, and pyspotify will not create a session for me. I tested this in the interpreter, removed tmp data that was stored, but still no luck. For more information, here's the error that I get:

```
Process:               Python [27626]
Path:                  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               2.7.6 (2.7.6)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        zsh [25534]
Responsible:           iTerm [2904]
User ID:               501

PlugIn Path:             /usr/local/lib/libspotify
PlugIn Identifier:       libspotify
PlugIn Version:          ??? (12.1.51)

Date/Time:             2014-11-03 22:12:17.830 -0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10 (14A389)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        FD561659-978C-63BF-2041-69A76232E0C1

Sleep/Wake UUID:       16F9C47F-785B-4B46-BE3A-760F2585F31F

Time Awake Since Boot: 170000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2600 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 00000001013fe000-00000001013ff000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libspotify                      0x0000000101c4b5c8 sp_session_set_private_session + 456
1   libspotify                      0x0000000101c4bb9c sp_session_create + 832
2   _cffi__xc487bcbdx74321873.so    0x0000000101afe3a4 _cffi_f_sp_session_create + 324 (_cffi__xc487bcbdx74321873.c:7243)
3   org.python.python               0x000000010148f180 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12778
4   org.python.python               0x000000010148bd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
5   org.python.python               0x000000010149257d 0x101408000 + 566653
6   org.python.python               0x000000010148f3e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
7   org.python.python               0x000000010148bd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
8   org.python.python               0x000000010143030a 0x101408000 + 164618
9   org.python.python               0x00000001014122ac PyObject_Call + 99
10  org.python.python               0x000000010148e9ba PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10788
11  org.python.python               0x000000010148bd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
12  org.python.python               0x000000010143030a 0x101408000 + 164618
13  org.python.python               0x00000001014122ac PyObject_Call + 99
14  org.python.python               0x000000010141d0cf 0x101408000 + 86223
15  org.python.python               0x00000001014122ac PyObject_Call + 99
16  org.python.python               0x00000001014593f4 0x101408000 + 332788
17  org.python.python               0x0000000101454cfb 0x101408000 + 314619
18  org.python.python               0x00000001014122ac PyObject_Call + 99
19  org.python.python               0x000000010148ec00 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 11370
20  org.python.python               0x000000010148bd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
21  org.python.python               0x000000010149257d 0x101408000 + 566653
22  org.python.python               0x000000010148f3e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
23  org.python.python               0x000000010148bd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
24  org.python.python               0x000000010148b7d7 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
25  org.python.python               0x00000001014ab7bd 0x101408000 + 669629
26  org.python.python               0x00000001014ab5d9 PyRun_InteractiveOneFlags + 353
27  org.python.python               0x00000001014ab0e8 PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags + 192
28  org.python.python               0x00000001014aaf92 PyRun_AnyFileExFlags + 60
29  org.python.python               0x00000001014bcb23 Py_Main + 3051
30  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff976005c9 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8af2656a semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libspotify                      0x0000000101b97040 0x101b19000 + 516160
2   libspotify                      0x0000000101b496c0 0x101b19000 + 198336
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e8d32fc _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e8d3279 _pthread_start + 176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e8d14b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8af2c5be poll + 10
1   libspotify                      0x0000000101c229ed 0x101b19000 + 1087981
2   libspotify                      0x0000000101b496c0 0x101b19000 + 198336
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e8d32fc _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e8d3279 _pthread_start + 176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8e8d14b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000101d27300  rbx: 0x00007f9413cfbc40  rcx: 0x00000000007f8000  rdx: 0x0000000000730e00
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000101578e00  rbp: 0x00007fff5e7ffba0  rsp: 0x00007fff5e7ffb80
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000800  r10: 0x0000000092dcc198  r11: 0x0000000092dd2b6f
  r12: 0x0000000000000fff  r13: 0x00007fff5e7ffbd0  r14: 0x00007f9413cfbc40  r15: 0x0000000000000018
  rip: 0x0000000101c4b5c8  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x0000000000000000

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x1013fe000 -        0x1013fefff  org.python.python (2.7.6 - 2.7.6) <A7B51404-B996-3FDF-A40F-0CCE1837F1F4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
       0x101408000 -        0x1014f9ff7  org.python.python (2.7.6 - 2.7.6) <A5C1B694-31A0-3966-B6BC-C40694DC707F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
       0x1016fd000 -        0x1016feff7  readline.so (89) <BC41F88F-29CB-30E8-8610-F1FA3F01219F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so
       0x101704000 -        0x101722fff  libedit.3.dylib (40) <6049084C-478A-3A89-A9A1-E641B5F8C1A7> /usr/lib/libedit.3.dylib
       0x101733000 -        0x101735fff  _collections.so (89) <4B0EB2CA-18E0-3F3A-B04B-94246814AF0F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_collections.so
       0x10173b000 -        0x10173efff  operator.so (89) <049C4902-93FF-3453-BFEA-99F6461E63C1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so
       0x101744000 -        0x101748fff  itertools.so (89) <76FA3C45-95A0-3627-A5D9-F6E43D7FE09A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so
       0x101791000 -        0x101792fff  _heapq.so (89) <DC500847-4C9E-3782-9F26-388082125F57> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so
       0x101797000 -        0x101798fff  time.so (89) <42DAC34B-013C-36E7-89A4-AE26FFBFD90E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so
       0x10179e000 -        0x10179ffff  cStringIO.so (89) <A2B6CB97-BCA1-3D64-BFC0-F5F9ED139A2C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cStringIO.so
       0x1017a4000 -        0x1017a7fff  strop.so (89) <EF7B9ADA-CB8F-350F-87CB-413F1E8398D7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/strop.so
       0x1017ec000 -        0x1017eefff  select.so (89) <6BC94C09-A797-3AE2-8294-EF46CACBC254> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/select.so
       0x1017f4000 -        0x1017f5fff  fcntl.so (89) <794692D1-C684-376C-AA4B-C1DBBD7C7A09> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/fcntl.so
       0x1017f9000 -        0x1017fcfff  _struct.so (89) <015BD869-7103-3735-A10A-70E4C15C9AB8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_struct.so
       0x101802000 -        0x101804fff  binascii.so (89) <CB8E5D83-F54B-3570-8667-06B951C38DB0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.so
       0x101948000 -        0x101952fff +_cffi_backend.so (0) <B3713068-2F4A-3436-9B0A-43927E9501EC> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_cffi_backend.so
       0x10199d000 -        0x10199efff  _hashlib.so (89) <706C58CB-4213-3845-B316-69D937257673> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so
       0x1019a2000 -        0x1019d7ff7  libssl.0.9.8.dylib (52) <70680606-475F-3C89-BB5F-E274253DC7C6> /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
       0x101aed000 -        0x101aedfff  grp.so (89) <DF55B2CB-E86C-3384-AB53-E183CE4B62A6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/grp.so
       0x101af1000 -        0x101b06fff +_cffi__xc487bcbdx74321873.so (0) <6C36D780-35BF-3765-88A9-62482D10A13F> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spotify/_cffi__xc487bcbdx74321873.so
       0x101b19000 -        0x101d1efef +libspotify (12.1.51) <F110EAC2-39E9-D6C6-F6DF-44CC8D009F28> /usr/local/lib/libspotify
       0x101d7b000 -        0x101d7cfff  _functools.so (89) <687C0F91-739D-3658-A815-C1CA87A0F4D3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_functools.so
       0x101dc1000 -        0x101dc8ff7  _socket.so (89) <F7E0FFD6-78FC-3F79-A0D2-8AF7266FEB93> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so
       0x101dd2000 -        0x101dd5fff  _ssl.so (89) <67507A0A-090E-3201-86BE-BE72B4CDFB47> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
       0x101ddb000 -        0x101ddbfff  _scproxy.so (89) <81735983-586E-3D32-8F57-95F8F860A8EB> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_scproxy.so
    0x7fff6327c000 -     0x7fff632b2837  dyld (353.2.1) <4696A982-1500-34EC-9777-1EF7A03E2659> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8ac77000 -     0x7fff8ac7eff7  libcompiler_rt.dylib (35) <BF8FC133-EE10-3DA6-9B90-92039E28678F> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff8af15000 -     0x7fff8af32fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2782.1.97) <93E0E0A9-75B6-3904-BB4E-4BC7C05F4B6B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff8b00d000 -     0x7fff8b00efff  liblangid.dylib (117) <B54A4AA0-2E53-3671-90F5-AFF711C0EB9E> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
    0x7fff8b017000 -     0x7fff8b047ff7  libncurses.5.4.dylib (44) <F09809A4-53B9-3E91-A8FA-D3F584C03AA3> /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
    0x7fff8b0de000 -     0x7fff8b0e8ff7  com.apple.NetAuth (5.0 - 5.0) <B9EC5425-D38D-308C-865F-207E0A98BAC7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetAuth.framework/Versions/A/NetAuth
    0x7fff8b0ee000 -     0x7fff8b18cfff  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 916) <DA8A1D18-19FE-37B3-BE12-85C5B0A00736> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff8b5bd000 -     0x7fff8b5c5ffb  libcopyfile.dylib (118.1.2) <0C68D3A6-ACDD-3EF3-991A-CC82C32AB836> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff8b77a000 -     0x7fff8b806fff  libsystem_c.dylib (1044.1.2) <C185E862-7424-3210-B528-6B822577A4B8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff8b852000 -     0x7fff8b858fff  libsystem_trace.dylib (72.1.3) <A9E6B7D8-C327-3742-AC54-86C94218B1DF> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x7fff8b904000 -     0x7fff8b92dffb  libxslt.1.dylib (13) <AED1143F-B848-3E73-81ED-71356F25F084> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
    0x7fff8b95f000 -     0x7fff8b98aff3  libarchive.2.dylib (30) <8CBB4416-EBE9-3574-8ADC-44655D245F39> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
    0x7fff8be4f000 -     0x7fff8be5fff7  libbsm.0.dylib (34) <A3A2E56C-2B65-37C7-B43A-A1F926E1A0BB> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x7fff8c8dc000 -     0x7fff8cb56fff  com.apple.CoreData (110 - 526) <AEEDAF00-D38F-3A15-B3C9-73732940CC55> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
    0x7fff8dce2000 -     0x7fff8dec7ff3  libicucore.A.dylib (531.30) <EF0E7544-E317-3550-A962-6AE65E78AF17> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff8e49e000 -     0x7fff8e4a0fff  com.apple.loginsupport (1.0 - 1) <35A2A071-606C-39A5-8C11-E4CAF98D934C> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/login.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/loginsupport.framework/Versions/A/loginsupport
    0x7fff8e7ae000 -     0x7fff8e802fff  libc++.1.dylib (120) <1B9530FD-989B-3174-BB1C-BDC159501710> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff8e8a5000 -     0x7fff8e8cfff7  libdispatch.dylib (442.1.4) <502CF32B-669B-3709-8862-08188225E4F0> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff8e8d0000 -     0x7fff8e8d9fff  libsystem_pthread.dylib (105.1.4) <26B1897F-0CD3-30F3-B55A-37CB45062D73> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff8eb20000 -     0x7fff8eb31ff7  libz.1.dylib (55) <88C7C7DE-04B8-316F-8B74-ACD9F3DE1AA1> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff8eb32000 -     0x7fff8eb32fff  com.apple.CoreServices (62 - 62) <9E4577CA-3FC3-300D-AB00-87ADBDDA2E37> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff8ed74000 -     0x7fff8edecff7  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.14 - 1.14) <C269BCFD-ACAB-3331-BC7C-0430F0E84817> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff8f028000 -     0x7fff8f029fff  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (100) <2EE8E436-5CDC-34C5-9959-5BA218D507FB> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff8f551000 -     0x7fff8f884fff  libmecabra.dylib (666) <2CE5540A-D412-3D53-9E11-86C24D61713B> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
    0x7fff8f8e5000 -     0x7fff8fc7bfff  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1151.16) <F2B088AF-A5C6-3FAE-9EB4-7931AF6359E4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff8fdeb000 -     0x7fff8fe13fff  libxpc.dylib (559.1.22) <9437C02E-A07B-38C8-91CB-299FAA63083D> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x7fff900b5000 -     0x7fff900baff7  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <BE7E51A0-B6EA-3A54-9CCA-9D88F683A6D6> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff90e54000 -     0x7fff90e6aff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (267) <F153AC5B-0542-356E-88C8-20A62CA704E2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff90e6b000 -     0x7fff90e6dff7  libquarantine.dylib (76) <DC041627-2D92-361C-BABF-A869A5C72293> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff90e7e000 -     0x7fff90e7ffff  libsystem_secinit.dylib (18) <581DAD0F-6B63-3A48-B63B-917AF799ABAA> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
    0x7fff90e80000 -     0x7fff90e84fff  libcache.dylib (69) <45E9A2E7-99C4-36B2-BEE3-0C4E11614AD1> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff91117000 -     0x7fff91142fff  libc++abi.dylib (125) <88A22A0F-87C6-3002-BFBA-AC0F2808B8B9> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff91194000 -     0x7fff911bffff  com.apple.DictionaryServices (1.2 - 229) <6789EC43-CADA-394D-8FE8-FC3A2DD136B9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fff911c0000 -     0x7fff911f8ffb  libsystem_network.dylib (411) <C0B2313D-47BE-38A9-BEE6-2634A4F5E14B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff91281000 -     0x7fff91283ff7  libsystem_coreservices.dylib (9) <41B7C578-5A53-31C8-A96F-C73E030B0938> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
    0x7fff91284000 -     0x7fff9128fff7  libkxld.dylib (2782.1.97) <CB1A1B57-54BE-3573-AE0C-B90ED6BAEEE2> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
    0x7fff91290000 -     0x7fff912eaff7  com.apple.LanguageModeling (1.0 - 1) <ACA93FE0-A0E3-333E-AE3C-8EB7DE5F362F> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/Versions/A/LanguageModeling
    0x7fff912eb000 -     0x7fff9134aff3  com.apple.AE (681 - 681) <7F544183-A515-31A8-B45F-89A167F56216> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff9152d000 -     0x7fff9185bff7  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1151.16) <18EDD673-A010-3E99-956E-DA594CE1FA80> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff9185c000 -     0x7fff91864fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (561.1.1) <62B70ECA-E40D-3C63-896E-7F00EC386DDB> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff91e14000 -     0x7fff91f35fff  com.apple.LaunchServices (644.10 - 644.10) <0B1C68BC-0AEB-38E2-ABC8-E92728FEC475> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
    0x7fff91f36000 -     0x7fff91f9dff7  com.apple.datadetectorscore (6.0 - 396.1) <5D348063-1528-3E2F-B587-9E82970506F9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/Versions/A/DataDetectorsCore
    0x7fff9208e000 -     0x7fff92092fff  libpam.2.dylib (20) <E805398D-9A92-31F8-8005-8DC188BD8B6E> /usr/lib/libpam.2.dylib
    0x7fff92227000 -     0x7fff9229dfe7  libcorecrypto.dylib (233.1.2) <E1789801-3985-3949-B736-6B3378873301> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff922eb000 -     0x7fff922fcfff  libcmph.dylib (1) <46EC3997-DB5E-38AE-BBBB-A035A54AD3C0> /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
    0x7fff9246d000 -     0x7fff92474fff  com.apple.NetFS (6.0 - 4.0) <1581D25F-CC07-39B0-90E8-5D4F3CF84EBA> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
    0x7fff924d0000 -     0x7fff924d3fff  com.apple.xpc.ServiceManagement (1.0 - 1) <7E9E6BB7-AEE7-3F59-BAC0-59EAF105D0C8> /System/Library/Frameworks/ServiceManagement.framework/Versions/A/ServiceManagement
    0x7fff92d47000 -     0x7fff92d47fff  libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib (162) <EFD79173-A9DA-3AE6-BE15-3948938204A6> /usr/lib/libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib
    0x7fff92d48000 -     0x7fff92d55ff7  libbz2.1.0.dylib (36) <2DF83FBC-5C08-39E1-94F5-C28653791B5F> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x7fff92d56000 -     0x7fff92d57ff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (65) <9615D10A-FCA7-3BE4-AA1A-1B195DACE1A1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff92d89000 -     0x7fff92d94fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60061) <D381EBC6-69D8-31D3-8084-5A80A32CB748> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff92d97000 -     0x7fff92d98fff  libSystem.B.dylib (1213) <DA954461-EC6A-3DF0-8551-6FC810627627> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff92d9e000 -     0x7fff92da6fff  libsystem_platform.dylib (63) <64E34079-D712-3D66-9CE2-418624A5C040> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff92db3000 -     0x7fff92dcdff7  liblzma.5.dylib (7) <1D03E875-A7C0-3028-814C-3C27F7B7C079> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
    0x7fff92dce000 -     0x7fff92dcffff  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent (2.0 - 25) <2D61A2C3-C83E-3A3F-8EC1-736DBEC250AB> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff92df5000 -     0x7fff9305dffb  com.apple.security (7.0 - 57031.1.35) <96141D1F-614E-32C4-8AC2-F47481F23F43> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
    0x7fff9311c000 -     0x7fff9311eff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (358.1.1) <DB9962EF-8898-31CC-9B87-E01F8CE74C9D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff9329c000 -     0x7fff9329cff7  libunc.dylib (29) <5676F7EA-C1DF-329F-B006-D2C3022B7D70> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff9351c000 -     0x7fff93536ff7  libextension.dylib (55) <17514AB2-C503-3D49-A725-EBC1140567A6> /usr/lib/libextension.dylib
    0x7fff935f6000 -     0x7fff9361efff  libsystem_info.dylib (459) <B85A85D5-8530-3A93-B0C3-4DEC41F79478> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff93a2e000 -     0x7fff93a3bff7  libxar.1.dylib (254) <CE10EFED-3066-3749-838A-6A15AC0DBCB6> /usr/lib/libxar.1.dylib
    0x7fff94ce5000 -     0x7fff94d2bff7  libauto.dylib (186) <A260789B-D4D8-316A-9490-254767B8A5F1> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff9544e000 -     0x7fff9546aff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (53.1.1) <19BCC257-5717-3502-A71F-95D65AFA861B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff954ea000 -     0x7fff954eefff  libsystem_stats.dylib (163.1.4) <1DB04436-5974-3F16-86CC-5FF5F390339C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
    0x7fff9550e000 -     0x7fff9550eff7  libkeymgr.dylib (28) <77845842-DE70-3CC5-BD01-C3D14227CED5> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff957d3000 -     0x7fff957d4ffb  libremovefile.dylib (35) <3485B5F4-6CE8-3C62-8DFD-8736ED6E8531> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff957df000 -     0x7fff957e5ff7  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (167.1.10) <29AB225B-D7FB-30ED-9600-65D44B9A9442> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
    0x7fff95e79000 -     0x7fff95e8aff7  libsystem_coretls.dylib (35.1.2) <EBBF7EF6-80D8-3F8F-825C-B412BD6D22C0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
    0x7fff96045000 -     0x7fff96128fff  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (52) <7208EEE2-C090-383E-AADD-7E1BD1321BEC> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff963de000 -     0x7fff963e3ff7  libmacho.dylib (862) <126CA2ED-DE91-308F-8881-B9DAEC3C63B6> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff964c8000 -     0x7fff964f8fff  libsystem_m.dylib (3086.1) <1E12AB45-6D96-36D0-A226-F24D9FB0D9D6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff965ae000 -     0x7fff9661dfff  com.apple.SearchKit (1.4.0 - 1.4.0) <BFD6D876-36BA-3A3B-9F15-3E2F7DE6E89D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fff967a1000 -     0x7fff967a2fff  libffi.dylib (18.1) <0F6C6A4D-1210-3585-8DA1-B8A94B9924A5> /usr/lib/libffi.dylib
    0x7fff967a3000 -     0x7fff967beff7  libCRFSuite.dylib (34) <D64842BE-7BD4-3D0C-9842-1D202F7C2A51> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
    0x7fff96d95000 -     0x7fff96e87ff7  libiconv.2.dylib (42) <2A06D02F-8B76-3864-8D96-64EF5B40BC6C> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    0x7fff96e91000 -     0x7fff96e99ffb  com.apple.CoreServices.FSEvents (1210 - 1210) <782A9C69-7A45-31A7-8960-D08A36CBD0A7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/FSEvents
    0x7fff96eca000 -     0x7fff970cdff3  com.apple.CFNetwork (720.0.9 - 720.0.9) <78EE1B88-394F-3BB8-93A6-E068990559EC> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff970e3000 -     0x7fff973caffb  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (1108.1 - 1108.1) <55A16172-ACC0-38B7-8409-3CB92AF33973> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff973d6000 -     0x7fff97453fff  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices (640.3 - 640.3) <28445162-08E9-3E24-84E4-617CE5FE1367> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
    0x7fff97454000 -     0x7fff9759afef  libsqlite3.dylib (168) <8B78BED1-7B9B-3943-80DC-0871015AEAC4> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x7fff9759b000 -     0x7fff9759fff7  com.apple.TCC (1.0 - 1) <AFC32F8F-BCD5-313C-B66E-5AB8591EC066> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/Versions/A/TCC
    0x7fff975fd000 -     0x7fff97600ff7  libdyld.dylib (353.2.1) <19FAF435-C165-3374-9DEF-D7BBA7D61DB6> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff989aa000 -     0x7fff98b8f267  libobjc.A.dylib (646) <3B60CD90-74A2-3A5D-9686-B0772159792A> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff98b90000 -     0x7fff98c01ff7  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1050.1.21) <ED3B0B22-AACC-303B-BFC8-20ECD1AF6BA2> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff98d3e000 -     0x7fff98d3eff7  liblaunch.dylib (559.1.22) <8A988924-8BE7-35FE-BF7D-322E90EFE49E> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff99005000 -     0x7fff99007fff  libsystem_configuration.dylib (699.1.5) <9FBA1CE4-97D0-347E-A443-93ED94512E92> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff99008000 -     0x7fff99021ff7  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory (10.10 - 187) <0ECA5D80-A045-3A2C-A60C-E1605F3AB6BD> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
    0x7fff99022000 -     0x7fff99114fff  libxml2.2.dylib (26) <B834E7C8-EC3E-3382-BC5A-DA38DC4D720C> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x7fff99678000 -     0x7fff99681ff7  libsystem_notify.dylib (133.1.1) <61147800-F320-3DAA-850C-BADF33855F29> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff99811000 -     0x7fff99816fff  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.6 - 2.6) <0DFF4D9B-2AC3-3B82-B5C5-30F4EFBD2DB9> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 89398
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=112.3M resident=28.2M(25%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=84.1M(75%)
Writable regions: Total=53.6M written=9780K(18%) resident=13.0M(24%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=40.6M(76%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
Kernel Alloc Once                     4K
MALLOC                             43.9M
MALLOC (admin)                       16K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              9232K
VM_ALLOCATE                          16K
__DATA                             5160K
__LINKEDIT                         70.7M
__TEXT                             41.6M
__UNICODE                           544K
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             226.8M

Model: MacBookAir6,2, BootROM MBA61.0099.B16, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 1.3 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.13f15
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5000, Intel HD Graphics 5000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3230554638454455302D474E2D4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3230554638454455302D474E2D4620
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.124.12.8)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.0f10 14890, 3 services, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD0128F, 121.33 GB
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 23.6
```

Comment: Oh wait guys I think I got it. You do have to remove the 'tmp' folder for some reason. Although, I don't really understand why. Looking into it.

Comment: Just to clarify, is this using pyspotify 1.x or 2.x? I presume 2.x given the cffi in tracebacks.

Comment: Yeah the version is  2.x